# Is it possible configure a jenkins maven project with inheritance?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm building up a set of jenkins configurations that are all maven based - so I want to use the maven project type to get the benefits of automated job build triggers ( which works well for me BTW ).

However, there are some parts of the job configurations that are common ( such as SCM locations, JDK version, maven versions, email address, post & pre-build steps etc ), so I would like to define these in one place.

The inheritance plugin, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/inheritance-plugin, works well, but I can't see that it helps maven projects ( since the inheritance project is close to a freestyle project ).

What are the best options to share common configurations across many maven jenkins jobs.

Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know the answer too. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Interested too :-)